# Uninstalling Java 8 on Mac 10.10 and installing java 6

Tags: java, macos, installation, uninstallation, osx-yosemite

I need to uninstall java 8 from my Mac 10.10, and install java 6.

Following one post here, i ran the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

The jdk8 is removed, but when i'm trying to install java 6 i'm getting an error as
"An updated version of java is already installed"

Can anyone guide me through..

Note:
- After running the commands, i did one system restart but no help
- I specifically need to install java 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of the not Unix-friendly users, this is the correct form to be executed in a Terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk*.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```